# Pandas Constant Values after each Zero Value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
    values
0      4
1      0
2      2
3      3
4      0
5      8
6      5
7      1
8      0
9      4
10     7
```

I want to find a pandas vectorized function (preferably using groupby) that would replace all nonzero values with the first nonzero value in that chunk of nonzero values, i.e. something that would give me

```
    values   new
0      4      4
1      0      0
2      2      2
3      3      2
4      0      0
5      8      8
6      5      8
7      1      8
8      0      0
9      4      4
10     7      4
```

Is there a good way of achieving this?

Comment: becuase looking back at rows,  you might need to consider `.apply()` as the vectorised method. would groupby() work here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a boolean mask to select the rows having zero and its following row, then  use this boolean mask with `where` to replace remaining values with `NaN`, then use forward fill to propagate the values in forward direction.

```
m = df['values'].eq(0)
df['new'] = df['values'].where(m | m.shift()).ffill().fillna(df['values'])
```

Result

```
print(df)

    values  new
0        4  4.0
1        0  0.0
2        2  2.0
3        3  2.0
4        0  0.0
5        8  8.0
6        5  8.0
7        1  8.0
8        0  0.0
9        4  4.0
10       7  4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

get rows for zeros, and the rows immediately after:

```py
zeros = df.index[df['values'].eq(0)]
after_zeros = zeros.union(zeros +1)
```

Get the rows that need to be forward filled:

```py
replace = df.index.difference(after_zeros)
replace = replace[replace > zeros[0]]
```

Set values and forward fill on `replace`:

```py
df['new'] = df['values']
df.loc[replace, 'new'] = np.nan
df.ffill()


values  new
0   4   4.0
1   0   0.0
2   2   2.0
3   3   2.0
4   0   0.0
5   8   8.0
6   5   8.0
7   1   8.0
8   0   0.0
9   4   4.0
10  7   4.0
```

Comment: This is also nice approach :)

Answer (score 1):

The following function should do the job for you. Check the comments in the function to understand the work flow of the solution.

```
import pandas as pd

def ffill_nonZeros(values):
    # get the values that are not equal to 0
    non_zero = values[df['values'] != 0]

    # get their indexes
    non_zero_idx = non_zero.index.to_series()

    # find where indexes are consecutive
    diff = non_zero_idx.diff()
    mask = diff == 1

    # using the mask make all places in non_zero where the change is consecutive equal None
    non_zero[mask] = None

    # fill forward (replace all None values with previous valid value)
    new_non_zero = non_zero.fillna(method='ffill')

    # put new values back in their indexs
    new = values.copy()
    new[new_non_zero.index] = new_non_zero

    return new
```

Now applying this function to your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([4, 0, 2, 3, 0, 8, 5, 1, 0, 4, 7], columns=['values'])
df['new'] = ffill_nonZeros(df['values'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    values  new
0        4    4
1        0    0
2        2    2
3        3    2
4        0    0
5        8    8
6        5    8
7        1    8
8        0    0
9        4    4
10       7    4
```